# How to swap a label for a button

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a label and I want to replace it with a new button.

How do I do this?

I can't see an methods for removing an element. Should I merely set it to not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `Label` and `Button` into `Grid` with as single `Row` and `Column` or any other parental control. Then simple manipulate the visibility of the controls on a specific event.

If you have to reuse such a UI Element than encapsulate the logic in a dedicated reusable control.

Comment: ah, so one needs a layout control as parent.